# Запятые в сложном предложении (авторский текст)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Теперь можно было причислить себя к этой братии благодаря форменной мантии и жить не впроголодь, а на весьма приличное жалование.**

Совершенно запуталась в запятых. Какой вариант правильный?

*Теперь можно было причислить себя к этой братии, благодаря форменной мантии, и жить не впроголодь, а на весьма приличное жалование.*

*Теперь можно было причислить себя к этой братии благодаря форменной мантии, и жить не впроголодь, а на весьма приличное жалование.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Производный предлог **благодаря**, который утратил признак добавочного действия, образован от деепричастия "благодаря" (методом перехода из одной части речи в другую).
Конструкции с предлогом **благодаря** являются, как правило, в предложении обстоятельствами с причинным значением ("благодаря" синонимичен непроизводному составному предлогу "из-за").

**Обычно обособляются** обороты, которые:
находятся не в начале и не в конце предложения;
содержат объяснение того, о чем говорится в предложении, и выделяются интонационно.
[Пунктуация в оборотах с производными предлогами](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1/)

Ориентируясь на правила, я бы обособила оборот (второй вариант пунктуации), возможно, даже заключила его скобки — уж больно он выбивается из структуры предложения.
Третий вариант однозначно неверный — перед **и** запятая не нужна, т. к. она соединяет однородные сказуемые.

**Теперь можно было причислить себя к этой братии (благодаря форменной мантии) и жить не впроголодь, а на весьма приличное жалование.**

Answer (score 0):

Как-то не звучит. Как вариант исправления:

**Теперь, благодаря форменной мантии,  можно было причислить себя к этой братии и жить не впроголодь, а на весьма приличное жалование.**